# How can I enable split-screen programmatically from inside my android app through on click button

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

My app contains a button through that button just want to trigger split screen functionality

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question. Good luck 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would probably involve using accessibility service. Are you interested in that? If yes, then i will share the code with you. Please reply

Answer (score -1):

**R.layout.activity_main (xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="startNewActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="297dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**R.layout.activity_second (xml)**

```
(Just a textView to keep it simple)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Second Activity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then your **MainActivity** launch second activity from first activity when Start button is clicked and set Flags. Rect takes care of the switching in division and activity option takes care of the transiting animation;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startNewActivity(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        
        Rect rt = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
        ActivityOptions actoptions = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
        ActivityOptions bounds = actoptions.setLaunchBounds(rt);
        
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

For this example, nothing I am going to leave the second activity as is.

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

**Finally and most importantly MainActivity.this in your manifest.xml file should look like this;**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:resizeableActivity="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

*To switch into multi window mode long press on the overview button and drag the app to one side of the screen*

**That's all.**

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `setSplitState(boolean)` to trigger split screen functionality

Example

inside button

```
onClick{
  ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if(manager != null){
     manager.setSplitState(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I cant find this function setSplitState